# Maven Release Plugin: Passing arguments to jib via command line does not work

Tags: maven, arguments, maven-release-plugin, jib

I migrated from Maven Release Plugin 2.5.1 to 3.0.0-M5.
I added jib:build as goal of release:perform.

Using version 2.5.1 I had no problem to pass arguments via -Darguments="-Djib.to.image=image -Djib.to.auth.username=username -Djib.to.auth.password=password" to nested Excecutions of the Release-plugin like jib:build.
Using the newer version the arguments are not passed to nested excecutions anymore. Does anybody know how to solve the problem?

Root pom.xml (Maven Release Plugin):

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
      <tagNameFormat>@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
      <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
      <releaseProfiles>releases</releaseProfiles>
      <checkModificationExcludes>
          <checkModificationExclude>*/package-lock.json</checkModificationExclude>
      </checkModificationExcludes>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Child pom.xml (jib-maven-plugin)

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
   <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.0</version>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
         <artifactId>jib-spring-boot-extension-maven</artifactId>
         <version>0.1.0</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <configuration>
       <to>
          <image>*imageDest*</image>
       </to>
       <container>
          <mainClass>*mainClass*</mainClass>
       </container>
       <pluginExtensions>
          <pluginExtension>        <implementation>com.google.cloud.tools.jib.maven.extension.springboot.JibSpringBootExtension</implementation>
          </pluginExtension>
       </pluginExtensions>
       <extraDirectories>
          <paths>
             <path>
                <from>*fromPath*</from>
                <into>*intoPath*</into>
             </path>
          </paths>
       </extraDirectories>
   </configuration>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <phase>deploy</phase>
         <goals>
            <goal>build</goal>
         </goals>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Please show the pom file...

Comment: `mvn -X` give debug logging.  It might contain useful information.